# JavaScript undefined check

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, undefined

I often see JavaScript code where a function may take in an "options" object and use it like:

```
var name = typeof options.name !== 'undefined' ? options.name : "Bob";
```

This seems like it would be equivalent to the following:

```
var name = options.name || "Bob";
```

Now, I understand that in certain situations you may actually care that `options.name` is `undefined` vs `null` and this makes sense to me, but I often see this in situations where this distinction is not necessary.

I believe I have heard that people write code like this because of some bug in IE. Can someone elaborate please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of the bug in IE, but those statements aren't exactly equivalent:

- The first one sets the `name` variable to the default `"Bob"` only when `options.name` is `undefined`.
- The second one sets the `name` variable to `"Bob"` whenever `options.name` is falsy. This can be an empty string, the `null` value, a value of `0`, the `NaN` value, the boolean value `false`, and also `undefined`.

For example, if `options.name === 0`, the first statement will set the `name` variable to `0`, while the second statement will set it to `"Bob"`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will depend on what the developer actually intends to do rather than whatever convention they subscribe to. In a lot of cases, the shorter `name = options.name || "Bob";` could end up giving you values you don't expect if you aren't aware of its actual behavior because it coerces a boolean value out of `options.name`. In other cases, other "falsy" values will be impossible (or nearly impossible): if the value is coming off a form element, for example, you don't really need to worry about `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0` -- it should always be a string as long as the form element exists -- so what this check would do is ensure that the field isn't a blank string (though any white space would get through). Another common pattern similar to `options.name || "Bob"` is `if (options.name) {...}`, which has the same potential problems/benefits.